# Firestore onSnapshot does not get initial values when app launches

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm building a mobile app using React Native and Redux and Firestore. I'm trying to fetch data in my componentDidMount method, but also listen for updates on that data. So I decided to use the onSnapshot method to listen to a users document in my database. So my redux action looks like this:

```
export const onUserDetailsChange = () => (dispatch) => {
  const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
  return firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(uid)
    .onSnapshot(
      (documentSnapshot) => {
        dispatch({
          type: RECEIVED_USER_DETAILS,
          payload: documentSnapshot.data(),
        });
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      },
    );
};
```

And my componentDidMount looks like this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.userDetailsListener = this.props.onUserDetailsChange();
  }
```

When I launch on the app using npx react-native run-ios, I verified that componentDidMount does get called. And it goes to the action and it even returns an unsubscriber from the onSnapshot. But my store never updates, and even console logs within the onSnapshot don't get called either. This is only on the initial launch. When I refresh the app, then everything works normally.

Is this a firestore issue? Is there something wrong with my onSnapshot? Or is it some sort of npm cache or DerivedData issue?

I've tried searching for this issue but haven't found anyone else who has had trouble getting the initial data fetch from onSnapshot.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any checks for errors.  Something could be going wrong and you'd never know.

Comment: That was dumb of me to not include that. But I just tried with the updated code and nothing was logged. Would it return an unsubscriber function even if it errors out?

Comment: Oh one more thing, just yesterday I updated my database rules to not allow any requests if the user isn't authenticated. I perform the onAuthStateChanged in my App.js on initial launch. Is it possible that this component tries to get the initial values before the onAuthStateChanged is run?

Comment: I think it could be worth to check it, try disabling the authentication rule and see if it loads properly. And what exactly you perform in the `onAuthStateChanged`? Afaik that's a callback to know when the user signs in or out.

Comment: I disabled the authentication rule but still no luck. In the onAuthStateChanged, if the user is signed in, I dispatch an action to set a user object in my store. If not, go to the login screen basically.

Comment: To clarify, your error is that `onSnapshot` doesn't trigger when there's an update while you haven't reloaded? Or that your query doesn't get called until you reload? I'm not familiar with react, but it seems to me that `onSnapshot` is not being called until you reload, thus it would be an issue with react. If you add a `console.log` does it show anything the second time (when it works)? Also, why do you refresh the data if it's supposed to update in real-time with Firestore?

Comment: That is correct. If I kill the simulator and the app and relaunch, the data is not pulled from the onSnapshot. But when I reload the app, it starts working normally. I don't have to refresh it anymore for it to pull updates. I think you're right though. I am using react-native-firebase and I checked their github, and this issue has been posted on there by someone else. I should have gone there first instead of stack overflow. But thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad to help! If you have some spare time feel free to create an answer and link the issue in there so more people with the same problem can easily find a solution to this problem.

Comment: @SishirMohan can you update the question with how you fixed it? I tried looking for an issue on the repo but haven't found any answers.